# Access from client to server on same machine by browser

Tags: client-server, reverse-proxy, httpserver

I have a simple question about client-server , please help me to solved it :

Assume that I have :

- Server A (Using apache http server )
- Web application B ( Also using another apache http server)
- A and B is located on the **same machine**

If on local browser , I access to a page from B ,and this page send a request to A :

`$.ajax { url: localhost:8080/service_from_A,..}`

It's work nomarly

And on browser from **another machine** I access to page from B ,and now ,the ajax request is failed because `url` is `localhost` of another machine

So , how can I access from another machine with above ajax calling (url still is `localhost` )then it could be exactly redirect server A . I do not want to fix IP address in ajax call

Answer (score 0):

On the computer running your Apache servers, get it's local IP address. For a Windows computer, you'd open up cmd.exe and type in

```
ipconfig
```

Then look for something that says "Wireless Adapter" if you're using a wireless connection or "Ethernet Adapter" if it's wired. Now look for the part that says "IPv4 Address" and read what's next to that.

I'm going to be *assuming* your local IPv4 address is 192.168.1.82

In your AJAX script, replace "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" with the IP address of your server host computer, in this case: "192.168.1.82".

Once you've done that, try connecting a computer that's on **the same LAN (Local Area Network)** as your host computer using the IP address of the host. To allow a computer from a different LAN to connect to your server, you need to do something called **port forwarding**.